# Limit of a function of three variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

I am using Mathematica 11.0. I want to find the limit at origin of the following function:

```
 f[x_, y_, z_] = (
   I q1 (2 y^3 z^4 + I y^2 z^6 + 8 y z^2 (4 + z^2) + 
     4 I z^4 (8 + z^2) + 
     2 x^2 y (4 I y z^2 + 4 (8 + z^2) + y^2 (8 + z^2))))/((-2 x^2 y + 
     2 y z^2 - I z^4) (-8 I + y (-4 + z^2)) (y (-4 + z^2) + 
     4 I (2 + z^2)) po)
```

where `po` is constant. How can it be done using the in-built `Limit` function?

Comment: `Limit[f[x, y, z], {x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 0}]`

Comment: `Limit[(I q1 (2 y^3 z^4+I y^2 z^6+8 y z^2 (4+z^2)+4 I z^4 (8+z^2)+2 x^2 y (4 I y z^2+4 (8+z^2)+y^2 (8+z^2))))/((-2 x^2 y+2 y z^2-I z^4) (-8 I+y (-4+z^2)) (y (-4+z^2)+4 I (2+z^2))* po),{x,y,z}->{0,0,0}]` answers `Indeterminate`.

Comment: @user64494 this feature doesn't work in my mathematica

Comment: @BillWatts It doesn't work. It gives me
```
       {(I q1 (2 y^3 z^4 + I y^2 z^6 + 8 y z^2 (4 + z^2) + 
    4 I z^4 (8 + z^2)))/((2 y z^2 - I z^4) (-8 I + 
    y (-4 + z^2)) (y (-4 + z^2) + 4 I (2 + z^2)) po), -((
  I q1 (8 + z^2))/(8 (2 + z^2) po)), -((
  I q1 (32 + 8 y^2))/((-8 I - 4 y) (8 I - 4 y) po))}
```

Comment: @Gaurav Maurya; Works in version 12.0. Upgrade your Mathematica.

Comment: v12 gives me $-\frac{i \text{q1}}{2 \text{po}}$

Comment: @Bill Watts: You calculate an iterated limit, not the three-dimensional limit. See Gelbaum&Olmsted, Counterexamples in analysis.

Comment: @yarchik @user64494 When I calculate Taylor's series using `Series`, only first orders, when x,y,z approaches zero, there is a finite answer. I am wondering how Mathematica is calculating it. We know at origin the function is undefined.

Comment: @Gaurav Maurya: Can you kindly support your statement  "When I calculate Taylor's series using Series, only first orders, when x,y,z approaches zero, there is a finite answer" by a formula? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 `Normal[Series[f[x,y,z], {z, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]]`

Comment: Iterating a series expansion is no safer than iterating a limit: both are order-dependent. Instead try `Normal[Series[f[t*x, t*y, t*z], {t, 0, 1}]] /. t -> 0` to see why the limit depends on path of approach (so `Indeterminate`, as note by @user64494, is correct).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no unique answer. The limit depends on the path by which you approach the origin. By parametrizing the path

```
Limit[f[a t, b t, c t],t->0]
```

we obtain

$$-\frac{i \text{q1} \left(2 a^2+c^2\right)}{4 \text{po} \left(a^2-c^2\right)}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider the limit of `f[x,y,z]` along the path

```
Limit[(I q1 (2 y^3 z^4 + I y^2 z^6 + 8 y z^2 (4 + z^2) + 
   4 I z^4 (8 + z^2) + 
   2 x^2 y (4 I y z^2 + 4 (8 + z^2) + 
      y^2 (8 + z^2))))/((-2 x^2 y + 2 y z^2 - I z^4) (-8 I + 
   y (-4 + z^2)) (y (-4 + z^2) + 4 I (2 + z^2)) po) /. {x -> t, 
   y -> t, z -> t}, t -> 0]
(*Indeterminate*)
```

This is rather math than Mathematica.

Answer (score 0):

While I get the same results as the other answers, there is a way to get **an** answer without using limits.

```
f[x, 0, z]
```

$-\frac{i\  \text{q1} \left(z^2+8\right)}{8\  \text{po} \left(z^2+2\right)}$

The $x$ dependency has disappeared.

```
% /. z -> 0
```

$-\frac{i\  \text{q1}}{2\  \text{po}}$

So this is a strange one.